# best way to enter only one time in a if block

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have a for cycle

```
for n= 1: 100
  x=rand()*10;
  if x > 5
    do something
  end
end
```

When I execute this cycle it happens that if x is major than 5, the program enter in if clause. I would create a way that enter in if clause only one time even if the condition is true.which could be the best way?In Java I'd created this using boolean but matlab doesn't have boolean type

Comment: "matlab doesn't have boolean type" -- yes, it does. It's called "logical", but it's the same thing. Look for `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for n= 1: 100
  x=rand()*10;
  y = 0
  if x > 5 && y == 0
    do something
    y = 1
  end
end
```